# Selenium Page Object Model page load timeout

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I feel like I'm clearly missing something. We have a java selenium-based browser automation framework. One method it provides is essentially this:

```
public <T extends Page> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    T page = (Page)pageClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    PageFactory.initElements(this.driverProvider.get(), page);
    return page;
}
```

This allows our testers to write code like this:

```
SearchResultsPage srp = get(SearchResultsPage.class);
... interact with srp
... do something that transitions the browser to the NextPage

NextPage np = get(NextPage.class);
... interact with np
```

Our `Page` objects look like your typical `Page` objects you see all over the internet. The question I have has to do with page load waits and how/where those need to be handled. Ideally, we don't want our testers to have to add waits in the test code. We want to encapsulate the waits (if needed) in the page object methods themselves. For example, lets say we have this method in `SearchResultsPage`:

```
void clickResult(int index) {
    WebElement elt = getResultWebElement(index);
    elt.click();  // results in sending the browser to a different page
}
```

So what happens on the `click()` call regarding page load waits? Who is responsible for waiting for the next page to load before execution continues and how can this generically be handled? It seems like `SearchResultsPage.clickResult` would have that responsibility, but what would it wait for? Given that the resulting browser page could vary, how would `SearchResultsPage.clickResult` even know what to wait for generically? We don't want to embed knowledge of `NextPage` into `SearchResultsPage` if we can avoid it. Alternatively, perhaps the test code could/should invoke something that does the wait, but then what does that look like? Perhaps the test code invokes a method on `NextPage` before starting to interact with it?

Comment: That would be in the FindsBy annotations.  In general Page Object Model frameworks do not use webdriverwaits.  (Usually they'll set the global implicit wait, though) You'd need to redefine the annotations to include them if you want explicit (and remove implicit).  In general each time an element (properties of the page model) is used it will fire the FindsBy annotation to get the element reference.  (This all depends on how the POM is implemented by the particular framework you are using...)  You should consider whether that type of architecture is suited for the site(s) you are testing.